# C# How to intercept clicking in button "Save As" Word 2013

Tags: c#, ms-word, save, vsto, add-in

I need to intercept the event that triggers after clicking on button "Save As" (Backstage View)
I managed to intercept the "Save" button through the Policy id = 3 or by idMso = FileSave but the "Save As" button can not.

Comment: Consider adding code snippet of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use DocumentBeforeSave event it has "saveas" parameter which tells if saveas was used, more details here

[Application.DocumentBeforeSave Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: thanks for your help I solved the problem,
you know if exists way to close the Backstage View by code ?
thanks

Comment: may be try RibbonUI.ActivateTabMso to switch to home tab

Answer (score 0):

For the case of the "Save" button I use the 
component ADXRibbonCommand of addin-express with 
the property "idMso = FileSave" and I use the 
"OnAction" event and this component intersects the event 
of "Save" button. For button "Save As" also works to Word 
2010 with property "idMso = FileSaveAs" but does not work in Word 2013

private void ribbonCommandFileSave_OnAction(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed, ADXCancelEventArgs e)
{

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

}

I like to get a similar way in order to work with the "Save As" option